# OMPython/OpenModelica parameter is not changeable

Tags: openmodelica

I have modeled a building in OpenModelica using Buildings library. I am curretly using OMPython and OMCSessionZMQ to set and optimize OpenModelica parameters in Python.

I just found out that for some parameters **isChangeable = False**, i.e., **mSenFac**, and I cannot use mod.setParameters( ) to set those parameters.

**mSenFac** can be found in Buildings.Fluid.MixingVolumes.MixingVolume, which is later used in Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.

Instead, I have been suggested to use
mod.sendExpression("setParameterValue(BuildingModels.oneElement, thermalZoneOneElement.mSenFac, 5), parsed = False)" and rebuild the model using mod.buildModel( ) API.

- BuildingModels.oneElement is my model name
- thermalZoneOneElement.mSenFac is the parameter I want to set.

However, this method also did not work for me, which I don't know why.

I need to be able to set **mSenFac** in iterations in an optimization algorithm. I would appreciate it if anyone can answer the following questions:

- Is it possible to make **isChangeable = True** for **mSenFac**?
- Is there any other way to set **mSenFac** using OMPython?

Best regards,
Farnaz

Comment: What is "BuildingModels"? A package or a model? What is "oneElement"?

Comment: Hello,
“BuildingModels” is a package, and “oneElement” is my model in that package.
When I use the OpenModelica API, isModel(BuildingModels.oneElement) returns True.

Comment: What is the type of component thermalZoneOneElement from your model?

Comment: thermalZoneOneElement is a model in Buildings library (Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement).

Answer (score 0):

Running this script:

```
loadString("
package BuildingModels
  model oneElement
    Integer mSenFacParameter = 1;
    Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZoneOneElement;
  end oneElement;
end BuildingModels;
"); getErrorString();

list(BuildingModels.oneElement); getErrorString();

// using setParameterValue can only set top level parameters
setParameterValue(BuildingModels.oneElement, mSenFacParameter, 6); getErrorString();

list(BuildingModels.oneElement); getErrorString();

// using setComponentModifierValue can set component modifiers
setComponentModifierValue(BuildingModels.oneElement, thermalZoneOneElement.mSenFac, $Code(=6)); getErrorString();

list(BuildingModels.oneElement); getErrorString();

// using setComponentModifierValue can set component modifiers
setComponentModifierValue(BuildingModels.oneElement, thermalZoneOneElement.mSenFac, $Code(=mSenFacParameter)); getErrorString();

list(BuildingModels.oneElement); getErrorString();
```

gives you:

```
true
""
"model oneElement
  Integer mSenFacParameter = 1;
  Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZoneOneElement;
end oneElement;"
""
Ok
""
"model oneElement
  Integer mSenFacParameter = 6;
  Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZoneOneElement;
end oneElement;"
""
Ok
""
"model oneElement
  Integer mSenFacParameter = 6;
  Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZoneOneElement(mSenFac = 6);
end oneElement;"
""
Ok
""
"model oneElement
  Integer mSenFacParameter = 6;
  Buildings.ThermalZones.ReducedOrder.RC.OneElement thermalZoneOneElement(mSenFac = mSenFacParameter);
end oneElement;"
""
```

Basically set the component modifier, build the code, simulate it, take the results.